# How to use JavaScript Array.find() method to make correct arithmetical calculation in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this simple calculation method which returns commission, I want to return calculated result from this **precents** array, I am trying to achieve this result with `Array.find` method, problem is when I pass  price `30` it's calculates from previous object `{min: 0, max: 30, percent: 30}` but i want to calculation start from `{min: 30, max: 40, percent: 29.70000000}` this object where `min` value is `30` How can I achieve this?

```js
function calculateCommisionValue(){
const percents = [{min: 0, max: 30, percent: 30}, {min: 30, max: 40, percent: 29.70000000},];
const result = percents.find(e => e.min <= 30 && e.max >= 30);
    return 30 * result?.percent / 100
}

//result should be 27.82215064
```

Comment: _"but i want to calculation start from `{min: 30, max: 40, percent: 29.70000000}`"_ - Why? `0 <= 30 && 30 >= 30` is true so the first object is valid.

Comment: You will always have this problem when you have overlapping boundaries. Change the first `max` to `29` and you're done.

Comment: Why not simply do: `return 30 * percents[1]?.percent / 100;`? Seems sufficient for the given situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Array.find()` method will return the first element that satisfies your condition. As you have set both `min` and `max` condition to be inferior/superior **or equal** you will have an issue when the max of a condition is the same as the min of the next one, as it will always return the first one.

You should decide which value will be inclusive and which one will be exclusive. From your question I understand that you want a max exclusive and min inclusive, to select the lower percentage value when the price is 30.

You should remove the equal in the second consition as such:

```js
function calculateCommisionValue(price: number) {
    const percents = [{min: 0, max: 30, percent: 30}, {min: 30, max: 40, percent: 29.70000000},];
    const result = percents.find(e => e.min <= price && e.max > price); // Remove the equal in the max consition
    return price * result?.percent / 100
}
```